# Using JSch to download all the files from remote FTP server to local machine

Tags: sftp, jsch

I have a use-case of downloading all the files present in a FTP server to my local machine through SFTP protocol. I am using JSch and it's `ChannelSftp` class to communicate to remote FTP server.

I see there are `ls` and `get` methods present in `ChannelSftp` class. So one way is to first get a list of all files using `ls` and then iterate and download files one by one using `get`.

Is there other better way to accomplish this task? Does ChannelSftp provides `mget *` kind of feature?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, ChannelSftp does not provide a `mget` method.

Your solution seems to be alright. If you really want to find another way, have a look at this example with `scp`: [ScpFrom.java](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpFrom.java.html)